# Why do Switch and ListView controls in MAUI not update with 2-way binding?

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui

This question is about two MAUI controls (`Switch` and `ListView`) - I'm asking about them both in the same question as I'm *expecting* the root cause of the problem to be the same for both controls. It's entirely possible that they're different problems that just share some common symptoms though. (`CollectionView` has similar issues, but other confounding factors that make it trickier to demonstrate.)

I'm using 2-way data binding in my MAUI app: changes to the data can either come directly from the user, or from a background polling task that checks whether the canonical data has been changed elsewhere. The problem I'm facing is that changes to the view model are not *visually* propagated to the `Switch.IsToggled` and `ListView.SelectedItem` properties, even though the controls do raise events showing that they've "noticed" the property changes. Other controls (e.g. `Label` and `Checkbox`) *are* visually updated, indicating that the view model notification is working fine and the UI itself is generally healthy.

Build environment: Visual Studio 2022 17.2.0 preview 2.1
App environment: Android, either emulator "Pixel 5 - API 30" or a real Pixel 6

The sample code is all below, but the fundamental question is whether this a bug somewhere in my code (do I need to "tell" the controls to update themselves for some reason?) or possibly a bug in MAUI (in which case I should presumably report it)?

## Sample code

The sample code below can be added directly a "File new project" MAUI app (with a name of "MauiPlayground" to use the same namespaces), or it's all available [from my demo code repo](https://github.com/jskeet/DemoCode/tree/main/MauiPlayground). Each example is independent of the other - you can try just one. (Then update `App.cs` to set `MainPage` to the right example.)

Both examples have a very simple situation: a control with two-way binding to a view-model, and a button that updates the view-model property (to simulate "the data has been modified elsewhere" in the real app). In both cases, the control remains unchanged visually.

Note that I've specified `{Binding ..., Mode=TwoWay}` in both cases, even though that's the default for those properties, just to be super-clear that that *isn't* the problem.

The `ViewModelBase` code is shared by both examples, and is simply a convenient way of raising `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` without any extra dependencies:

**ViewModelBase.cs:**

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MauiPlayground;

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        field = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Switch sample code

**SwitchDemo.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiPlayground.SwitchDemo">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Switch binding demo" />
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Switch x:Name="switchControl"
                    IsToggled="{Binding Toggled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Toggled="Toggled" />
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Toggled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Toggled}" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <Button Text="Toggle" Clicked="Toggle" />
        <Label x:Name="manualLabel1" Text="Value set in button click handler" />
        <Label x:Name="manualLabel2" Text="Value set in toggled handler" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**SwitchDemo.cs**

```cs
namespace MauiPlayground;

public partial class SwitchDemo : ContentPage
{
    public SwitchDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void Toggle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = (ViewModel)BindingContext;
        vm.Toggled = !vm.Toggled;
        manualLabel1.Text = $"Set in click handler: {switchControl.IsToggled}";
    }

    private void Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e) =>
        manualLabel2.Text = $"Set in toggled handler: {switchControl.IsToggled}";

    private class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool toggled;
        public bool Toggled
        {
            get => toggled;
            set => SetProperty(ref toggled, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the emulator after clicking on the "Toggle" button, which updates the view-model:

[image: Demonstration of Switch issue]

Notes:

- The checkbox (bound to the same VM property) has updated
- The label next to the checkbox (bound to the same VM property) has updated
- The label below the button indicates that `switch.IsToggled` is true
- The label below that indicates that the `Switch.Toggled` event has been raised
- The `Switch` itself has not changed visible state

Clicking on the `Switch` control directly *does* visually toggle it.

### ListView sample code

**ListViewDemo.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiPlayground.ListViewDemo">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="ListView binding demo" />
        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  VerticalOptions="Start"
                  ItemSelected="ItemSelected"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
        <Button Text="Toggle" Clicked="Toggle" />
        <Label x:Name="manualLabel1" Text="Text set in button click handler" />
        <Label x:Name="manualLabel2" Text="Text set in item selected handler" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**ListViewDemo.cs**

```cs
namespace MauiPlayground;

public partial class ListViewDemo : ContentPage
{
    public ListViewDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void Toggle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = (ViewModel)BindingContext;
        vm.SelectedItem = vm.SelectedItem == "First" ? "Second" : "First";
        manualLabel1.Text = $"Set in click handler: {listView.SelectedItem}";
    }

    private void ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        manualLabel2.Text = $"Set in item selected handler: {listView.SelectedItem}";

    private class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public List<string> Items { get; } = new List<string> { "First", "Second" };

        private string selectedItem = "First";
        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get => selectedItem;
            set => SetProperty(ref selectedItem, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the emulator after clicking on the "Toggle" button, which updates the view-model:

[image: Demonstration of ListView issue]

Notes:

- The label below the list view (bound to the same VM property) has updated
- The label below the button indicates that `listView.SelectedItem` has the new value
- The label below that indicates that the `ListView.ItemSelected` event has been raised
- The `ListView` itself appears to have *no* selected item

Interestingly, the list view *does* actually change appearance: before clicking on the button, the first item is visually selected (in orange). Selecting an item from the list manually updates all the properties, but we *don't* see the selected item in orange.

Comment: I didn't realize Jon Skeet asked questions!!  My assumption is that this is just a bug in pre-release MAUI.  Also, AFAIK specifying `TwoWay` is not required, as user interactive controls will default to that.

Comment: @Jason: Yup, I realized that TwoWay was the default, but I figured if I specified it explicitly, it would save anyone guessing that I needed to do it :) Will clarify that in the question.

Comment: In Xamarin I faced similar issue. Some properties didn't have bindings in the SDK and I had to read a source code of the component and then I modified this component in the custom renderer.

Comment: When legend ask question the bug will resolve itself.

Comment: A master class on questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue with `Switch.IsToggled` is known and [has been fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/5276) but won't be available until the next RC is published (6.0.300-rc.1).

I haven't found any reported issues regarding the `ListView` problem but I was able to reproduce it. It seems to be caused by the default `ViewCell` created for each item. It can be fixed by specifying a custom `ListView.ItemTemplate` like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        ItemSelected="ItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 5):

These both may be bugs with the currently released version of MAUI.

This [bug was recently posted](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5226) and there is [already a fix](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/5276) for the Switch to address this issue.

Comment: Thanks very much - I did look for existing bugs before posting (and found one about CollectionView) but missed both of those.